# Promoting Tor on Project for Awesome

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I'm planning on promoting Tor in the upcoming [Project for Awesome](http://www.projectforawesome.com/) 2014. Within my video, I plan on pointing people to this site, but linking to the site tour/rules first.

Here is [the script](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gqQt-IKJCpjaFYYKg2JyHfl1vHeOOX42Fn5Vgi72gAQ/edit?usp=sharing) for the video that I plan on making. Is there anything in here that is inaccurate or that I should modify? Do I make it clear enough about what this site should be used for?

I thought I would post this on Meta since it's more discussion oriented and deals with the community as a whole.

**UPDATE:**
You can watch the final (somewhat brutal) result [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zt5pjH68EMY).

Comment: If you ever spell Tor in a lower third or a title card or something, make sure it's "Tor" not "TOR". You did this right in your question, but there are a few "TOR"s in the script.

Comment: Also, saying that criminals have "cheaper" tools gives the impression that Tor costs money.

Comment: @SamWhited That's a good point. How should I phrase it instead that criminals have different priorities that Tor has?

Comment: Hmm... Tough call; I hate to say it, but I think criminals DO use it (and heavily). I don't buy the argument that they have better tools. But obviously you probably don't want to emphasize that :) maybe that's some marketing or press materials on the website that could help you phrase this?

Comment: Found the [materials](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq-abuse.html.en). I'll just rephrase them.

Comment: Good material there, thanks for the link.